# Django Form ChoiceField how to show more field name

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

i have a "little" problem. I want get ALL ModelChoiced field and don't know how to do that.

My code parts

models.py

```
class Materials(models.Model):
    material = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    density = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.material

class Items(models.Model):
   article_number = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
   quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
   material = models.ForeignKey('Materials',on_delete=models.PROTECT,blank=True,null=True)
   surface =models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
   .
   .
   .
```

forms.py

```
class ItemsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Items
        fields = "__all__"
```

views.py

```
def new(request):
   items_form = forms.ItemsForm()
   context = {
      'items_form':items_form,
   }
   return render(request,"new.html",context)
```

new.html

```
{{ items_form.article_number }}
{{ items_form.quantity }}
{{ items_form.material }}
{{ items_form.surface}}
.
.
.
```

So now, when open link, the generated html material code is

```
<select name="material" id="id_material">
   <option value selected>---------</option>
   <option value="id_1">"material_1"</option>
   <option value="id_2">"material_2"</option>
   <option value="id_3">"material_3"</option>
</select>
```

I want represent all Materials field value on each input, like this:

```
<select name="material" id="id_material">
   <option value selected>---------</option>
   <option value="id_1">"material_1"</option>
   <option value="id_2">"material_2"</option>
   <option value="id_3">"material_3"</option>
</select>

<select name="density" id="id_density">
   <option value selected>---------</option>
   <option value="id_1">"density_1"</option>
   <option value="id_2">"density_2"</option>
   <option value="id_3">"density_3"</option>
</select>

<select name="price" id="id_price">
   <option value selected>---------</option>
   <option value="id_1">"price_1"</option>
   <option value="id_2">"price_2"</option>
   <option value="id_3">"price_3"</option>
</select>
```

I tryed adding these line in ItemsForm but this method not get 'id', only just values:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ItemsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['density'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.Materials.objects.values_list('density',flat=True))
```

Comment: Remove `__all__` from `fields` in `ModelForm`, and manually give all the fields.

Comment: @Sunderam it's nothing happened, same problem

Comment: You have wrote `'Materials'`, rather than `Materials`, while making foreign key.

Comment: @Sunderam It is not part of the question

Comment: well, what you would like to do?, you can't access it as you stated,you'll get this type of output only if you make `three` other columns like in your case they are `material,density and price` and then you have to make another three tables respectively, and attach it with foreign key then you'll get this type of output. if you like, notify me i can tell you in answer.

Comment: @Sunderam When the user selected a material, it should be see the material price and density for each and total quantity before submit form. So if i get the rest field i can this with javascript.